# What does the line $(rpm -E %fedora) mean?

Tags: fedora, rpm, repository

I'm trying to add a new repository to my Fedora and was asked to introduce the following command:

```
su -c 'yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'
```

I'm trying to understand what every part of the command means, and almost have it all, except for the line `$(rpm -E %fedora)`. I googled it but found nothing, so I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It runs the command `rpm -E %fedora` and substitutes its output from stdout into the outer command.

`rpm -E` evaluates the variable(s) in the text passed to it.

Comment: I see, so it returns the version of Fedora I am running. Thanks.

Comment: `$()` is a better version of the increasingly deprecated `\`\`` subshell notation.

Answer (score 1):

#### RPM Macros

When you have questions like this it's best to consult the man pages. Take a look at the `rpm` man page.

```
$ man rpm
...
   -E, --eval='EXPR'
          Prints macro expansion of EXPR.
```

Realizing that `%fedora` is a macro if you go a bit further down in the `rpm` man page you can see what files provide macro definitions.

```
Macro Configuration
    /usr/lib/rpm/macros
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/macros
    /etc/rpm/macros
    ~/.rpmmacros
```

Taking a peek inside of `/etc/rpm/macros` will reveal this definition.

```
$ grep fedora /etc/rpm/macros*
/etc/rpm/macros.dist:%fedora                19
```

So we can see that there is a definition called `%fedora` and on my system (Fedora 19) it has a value of "19".

#### Inline command execution

The notation `$(..)` will execute whatever command is between the parenthesis and substitute the returned results in their place.

#### Example

```
$ echo $(echo hi)
hi
```

Or in your case:

```
$ echo $(rpm -E %fedora)
19
```

#### Putting it all together

So when the command you're asking about runs the following things happen. A RPM macro, `%fedora` is evaluated using the `rpm` command. That command is executed in line. Once expanded to "19" that value is used within the larger `yum` command to install the appropriate `.rpm` file for a given version of Fedora.